# actuator/health - No WebApplicationContext found: no ContextLoaderListener registered?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-boot-actuator

I was able to configure spring-boot-actuator at some point without using spring-boot but when I try to hit "http://localhost:8080/spring-rest-demo/actuator/health" I'm getting

java.lang.IllegalStateException: No WebApplicationContext found: no ContextLoaderListener registered?

What am I missing?
Is it because I'm using `@EnableAutoConfiguration`?

[image: error]

Other actuator endpoints are working without issues, i.e:
[image]

[image]

DemoAppConfig.java

```java
package com.andres.springdemo.config;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.endpoint.EndpointAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.Health;
import org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthIndicator;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;

@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = { DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class, HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class })
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan("com.andres.springdemo")
@PropertySource(value = { "classpath:application.properties" })
public class DemoAppConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    @Override
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.enable();
    }

}
```

MySpringMvcDispatcherServletInitializer.java

```java
package com.andres.springdemo.config;

import org.springframework.web.servlet.support.AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer;

public class MySpringMvcDispatcherServletInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[] { DemoAppConfig.class };
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[] { "/" };
    }
    
    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

}
```

pom.xml

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.andres</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-rest-demo</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.13.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Add Jackson for JSON converters -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.13.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.23</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Add Spring MVC and REST support -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.23</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Add Servlet support for 
             Spring's AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-actuator -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.3</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <!-- Support for Maven WAR Plugin -->
    <build>
        <finalName>spring-rest-demo</finalName>

        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.2.0</version>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: Are you or aren't you using Spring Boot... That part is totally confusing in your question.

Comment: No, I'm NOT using Spring Boot @M.Deinum